# How to handle checking of invalid credentials for container and SOAP

Tags: yodlee

I am working through the flow for Refresh_Account for Container using SOAP API:

http://developer.yodlee.com/Aggregation_API/Aggregation_Services_Guide/API_Flow/Refresh_Account

Is it possible to find out the login credentials are correct before IsItemRefreshing returns false. E.g. I want to be able to inform the user that they have given correct credentials and then process refresh in background.

I can see how this is handled for site but not container.

Answer (score 0):

In short there is no way even before calling isItemRefreshing to know whether the passed credentials are correct or not.

In detail, below is the process:

1. Client submit the user's credentials to Yodlee and start a refresh to fetch the details of the accounts which belongs to those credentials of a particular bank site.
2. Yodlee uses those credentials to login on behalf of user, once you trigger a refresh process.
3. Bank site validates those credentials and either successfully shows the post login page or shows error message mentioning that the provided credentials are incorrect.
4. Then only client can get that whether the credentials are incorrect.

Yodlee recommend you to use Site Based approach, as in that client will get intermediate response whether the Login was successful or not and depending upon the status client can inform the user whether they need to enter correct credentials or login is successful.